# Code Gives an error when input is a string when trying to change to an int, try/except does not catch it

Tags: python, json, printing, integer, wmic

I am writing a piece of python code that allows you to switch your default printer. It outputs the data of `wmic printer list brief` to a .json file and lists those printers out with an assigned number. If the input is not included in the numbers it throws an error to the user. If the user inputs a character instead of a number the conversion from string to int fails and I cannot get a try/except to catch the error. Any help would be awesome!

```
    def setDefaultPrinter():
    with open('resources/data.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        loopvalue = 1
        print('\n List of avalible printers: \n')
        printerlist = []
        error = False
        for i in data:
            print(str(loopvalue) + ". " + i)
            loopvalue += 1
            printerlist.append(i)
            #any(printer in x for x in lst)
        try:
            global printer
            printer = int(input("\nWhat printer do you want to use? (Number on the side): "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a number, not a letter")
            error = True
        except Exception:
            print("Internal Error")
        try:
            if printer == None:
                print("Error")
        except Exception:
            print("ERROR")
            error = True
        if printer <= len(printerlist) and not error:
            printer = int(printer)
            printervalue = printer - 1
            printername = printerlist[printervalue]
            print(printername)
        else:
            if error == False:
                print("Invalid Responce")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def setDefaultPrinter():
with open('resources/data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    loopvalue = 1
    print('\n List of avalible printers: \n')
    printerlist = []
    error = False
    for i in data:
        print(str(loopvalue) + ". " + i)
        loopvalue += 1
        printerlist.append(i)
        #any(printer in x for x in lst)
    printer = input("\nWhat printer do you want to use? (Number on the side): ")
    if not printer.isdigit():
        error = True
        print("\nValue Error: Please Check Your Input")
    if not error and int(printer) <= len(printerlist):
        printer = int(printer)
        printervalue = printer - 1
        printername = printerlist[printervalue]
        print(printername)
    else:
        if error == False:
            print("Invalid Responce")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).